# Run Script within Batch File with Parameters

Tags: powershell, batch-file, parameters, arguments

I'm writing a Batch File, and in this batch file i execute a script.

Batch File:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""C:\Public\File\SomeScript.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

Now this works fine.

Is it possible to execute the SomeScript.ps1 with parameters ?

Like

```
@echo off
echo %1
echo %2
echo %3
echo %4
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""C:\Public\File\SomeScript.ps1 Arg1 %1 Arg2 %2 Arg3 %3 Arg4 %4""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

The Batch File echos the values I'm giving. But after that nothing happens. So I'm not sure if I'm passing the Arguments correctly.

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The arguments must be *outside* the quoted script path, `""C:\Public\File\SomeScript.ps1""`
- To be safe, you should double-quote the arguments too.
- Use `\"` to escape embedded double quotes when calling the CLI of *Windows PowerShell* (`powershell.exe`) as in your case), and `""` for *PowerShell (Core)* (`pwsh.exe`).

  - Note: Depending on the specific values of the pass-through arguments, use of `\"` with Windows PowerShell can break, due to `cmd.exe`'s limitations; the - ugly - workaround is to use `"^""` (sic).

Therefore (limited to passing `%1` for brevity):

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Start-Process PowerShell '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \"C:\Public\File\SomeScript.ps1\" Arg1 \"%1\"' -Verb RunAs"
```

---

As an aside: There's no reason to use `& { ... }` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `...` directly, as shown above. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

Comment: Hi mklement0, I am not that big of a Powershell user but I do read the ones that are tagged with `batch-file`.  From time to time I see this double usage of executing Powershell.  What is the purpose of that?

Comment: @Squashman, it is necessary in order to create an _elevated_ process, which cannot be done directly: the first `powershell` call invokes `Start-Process -Verb RunAs`, which creates an elevated (run as admin) process. In this case, it is _another_ PowerShell process, but you can use the technique to launch any program with elevation.