# Run powershell script as administrator via batch file with parameter passing

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-10-universal, powershell-5.0

When I run the script, without an administrator, via batch file it passes the parameter, but when I run the script, as an administrator, it does not pass the parameter.

I'm trying the command in the link below, but with no success:
[run-script-within-batch-file-with-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69285963/run-script-within-batch-file-with-parameters)

Command that executes the script, as an administrator, via batch file:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "D:\z_Batchs e Scripts\Batchs\Normaliza_LUFS\ArqsNorms_LUFS_pass.ps1' '%_vLUF%'  -Verb RunAs}"
```

The `%_vLUF%` is the parameter to be passed.

Error message:

```
No line:1 character:4
+ & {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolic ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Command in powershell script to receive the parameter:

```
Param(
     [decimal]$env:_vLUF
)
```

What could be wrong, the command in the batch file or in the powershell script?

`Test:`
When the script is executed, without being an administrator, via batch file and the Parameter in the powershell script is defined as:

Parameter in powershell:

```
Param(
     [decimal]$env:_vLUF
)
```

Command in the batch file running the script without being an administrator:

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File "D:\z_Batchs e Scripts\Batchs\Normaliza_LUFS\ArqsNorms_LUFS_pass.ps1" %_vLUF%
```

Note:
No need to use a named argument with the target parameter name.

Result:
[image]

Conclusion:
When the script is running, without being an administrator, via a batch file it works correctly even if the parameter used in the script is defined as an environment parameter, eg: `[decimal]$env:_vLUF` and regardless of the parameter value being negative, eg : `-11.0`.

Why Powershell when running a script without being as an administrator correctly interprets the minus sign in the argument and when run as an administrator it does not interpret the minus sign correctly is a question I leave to the experts!

However, my question was very well answered by Mr. @mklement0.

Comment: Your quoting is an issue. Right before your path, you have a double quote terminating the first call there.

Comment: @Abraham Zinala what is the correct way?

Comment: Escape the quote (also provide it's ending quote), or escape the spaces in the path.

Comment: @Abraham Zinala I put double quotes at the end of the path, that's it? `"D:\z_Batchs e Scripts\Batchs\Normaliza_LUFS\ArqsNorms_LUFS_pass.ps1"'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your **`.ps1` script's parameter declaration is flawed**:

```
Param(
     [decimal]$env:_vLUF  # !! WRONG - don't use $env:
)
```

See the bottom section for more information.

It should be:

```
Param(
     [decimal] $_vLUF  # OK - regular PowerShell variable
)
```

Parameters in PowerShell are declared as *regular* variables, not as *environment* variables (`$env:`).

(While environment variables can be passed as an *argument* (parameter *value*), an alternative is to simply reference them by name directly in the body of your script.)

---

Your **PowerShell CLI call has problems too, namely with quoting**.

Try the following instead:

```bash
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \"D:\z_Batchs e Scripts\Batchs\Normaliza_LUFS\ArqsNorms_LUFS_pass.ps1\" -_vLUF %_vLUF%'"
```

Specifically:

- *Embedded* `"` chars. must be escaped as `\"` (sic) when using the Windows PowerShell CLI (`powershell.exe`); however, given that `%_vLUF%` represents a `[decimal]`, you needn't quote it at all.

  - However, **you appear to have hit a *bug*** that affects PowerShell versions up to at least 7.2.4 (current as of this writing): if the argument starts with `-`, such as in negative number `-11.0`, the `-File` CLI parameter invariably interprets it as a *parameter name* - even quoting doesn't help. See [GitHub issue #17519](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17519).
  - The **workaround**, as used above is to use a *named* argument, i.e. to precede the value with the target parameter name: `-_vLUF %_vLUF%`
- As an aside: There's no reason to use `& { ... }` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `...` directly, as shown above. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

---

As for the **broken attempt to use `[decimal]$env:_vLUF` as a *parameter* declaration**:

```
Param(
     [decimal]$env:_vLUF  # !! EFFECTIVELY IGNORED
)
```

is *effectively ignored*.

However, if an environment variable `_vLUF` happens to be defined, it *is* accessible in the body of a script, *independently of which parameters, if any, have been passed*.

- In *direct* invocation of your `.ps1` script from your batch file, `_vLUF` indeed exists as an environment variable, because in `cmd.exe` (the interpreter of batch files), variables are invariably also *environment* variables - unlike in PowerShell.

  - That is, if `%_vLUF%` has a value in your batch file, a `powershell` child process you launch from it automatically sees it as `$env:_vLUF`
- By contrast, if you launch an *elevated* process via `Start-Process` from such a PowerShell child process, that new, elevated process does *not* see the caller's environment variables - by security-minded design.

Note:

- That PowerShell even *syntactically accepts* `[decimal]$env:_vLUF` as a parameter declaration should be considered a *bug*.
- What happens is that a *regular* variable named `env:_vLUF` is indeed created and bound, if an argument passed to it, but on trying to *get the value of* that variable in the body of your script, it is preempted by the *environment* variable.

  - As such, an invocation can *break*, namely if the parameter is type-constrained and you pass a value that cannot be converted to that type (`[decimal]` in the case at hand).
  - If the invocation doesn't break, the type constraint is *ignored*: `$env:_vLUF` is invariably of type `[string]`, as all environment variables are.

Comment: I used the command you posted and changed my powershell script to: `Param( [decimal]$_vLUF )`. The Value sent by the command in the batch file is `11.0` but it is being received in the powershell script as `0`. How to make the value be sent correctly?

Comment: sorry, the values sent will always be negative, so the value sent is `-11.0`, ok?

Comment: That's the problem, @Clamarc - and it smells like a bug in how the PowerShell CLI parses `-File` arguments; please see my update (both the updated command itself and the amended explanation).

Comment: I posted a test on my question running the script without being as an admin via batch file, it would be interesting for you to analyze it.

Comment: another detail... the powershell screen opens and closes quickly when the script is executed, is there a way to make this screen not appear?

Comment: @Clamarc, I see the problem with needing to precede negative numbers with the target parameter name in non-admin calls too, and I've reported it at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17519. The bug report is for PowerShell _Core_, so to test it in _Windows PowerShell_, replace `pwsh` with `powershell.exe`

Comment: @Clamarc, re the PowerShell window flashing: it's probably the _batch file_ that causes the flashing, which happens whenever you call a console application from outside an existing console window, such as by double-clicking the batch file in File Explorer. As for techniques to run console applications hidden, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67761779/45375).

Comment: See the `test` in my question. If the script is executed without being an administrator and we define in the script parameter the variable as if it were an environment variable, eg. `[decimal]$env:_vLUF` the script recognizes the negative sign without any problem and receives the variable normally. If the script is run without being an administrator and we define the variable as normal in the script parameter, eg. `[decimal] $_vLUF` the script has an error and does not recognize the negative value, that is, `[decimal]$env:_vLUF` works, `[decimal] $_vLUF` does not work.

Comment: @Clamarc, ah, I missed the `$env:_vLUF` angle - please see my update (new bottom section). The short of it: your `param()` declaration is effectively ignored and only works _accidentally_ in direct (non-elevated) invocation. In an elevated invocation, it predictably fails.

Comment: Ok, let's wait for the GitHub working group to analyze the bug. Another detail regarding the bug: I asked a question on the Superuser website that no one could answer and after several tests I found that the problem is related to the behavior of Powershell when executed via batch file as non-admin. In my tests, the Out-file command gives different results. I answered my question myself, so if you can see my answer there on Superuser the link is: https://superuser.com/questions/1725299/powershell-commands-not-working-correctly-via-batch-file