# How to pass arguments to PowerShell script executed as administrator from batch script?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a PowerShell script that needs to be executed using Windows' Batch Script as Administrator. The script is running without arguments, however when I pass arguments, the PowerShell window pops up and closes instantly. Here is what I have tried.

Batch script

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Start-Process PowerShell '-NoProfile - 
ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \"D:\batch_scripting\test2.ps1" -FolderPath \"test"'   -Verb 
RunAs"
```

Powershell

```
param
(
 [string]$FolderPath ='D:\batch_scripting'
 )

echo $FolderPath
pause
```

I will add further functionalities in these scripts later. But I have to figure out this first.
The script can be executed if **-FolderPath** argument is not passed.

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Start-Process PowerShell '-NoProfile - 
ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \"D:\batch_scripting\test2.ps1"' -Verb 
RunAs"
```

I have also gone through following questions but this does not work for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72563402/run-powershell-script-as-administrator-via-batch-file-with-parameter-passing?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69285963/run-script-within-batch-file-with-parameters

Comment: Use the `-ArgumentList` switch  to pass arguments.

Comment: Your examples are incorrect because they should be on a single line, not over three. Also, you do not need the first ```-ExecutionPolicy Bypass``` either.

Comment: tried -ArgumentList, same problem.

Comment: It is a single line actually. What's incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, although it's weird.
When you execute the powershell script as Administrator, trailing "/" must be added to the path of the script.

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Start-Process PowerShell 'NoProfile - ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \"D:\batch_scripting\test2.ps1\"' -Verb RunAs"
```

It works fine now.